# 90's or 00's show/movie - Teens with super suit

Tags: identify-this-movie, identify-this-tv-show

It was a live-action, can't remember if its a show or a movie (I was really young then), but here's everything that I can remember:

Three teens (two boys and a girl) found an old device (in a garage, maybe) with a black and white picture showing a digital image of someone's face on it. He gives them a silver colored super suit that increases strength; they used it to get rid of some bullies. Later, the superhero gives the girl something that can make her invisible.

He also tells them that there's a supervillain named Crab or The Crab (not sure if it's the correct name).

Meanwhile, the supervillain (who is, by the way, an old man in a wheelchair) gives his granddaughter (or maybe just a teen girl) a super suit that increases speed (she was able to make an acrobatic move immediately).

Also, I remember that some kind of a malfunction came over the superhero's device that made it forget things (something like amnesia), but one of the two boys was able to fix it.

Comment: Is the crab a human, animal, half-half, alien ?

Comment: @Lordofdark I guess he was an old man in a wheelchair.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Legacy of the Silver Shadow

Could it be [Legacy Of The Silver Shadow](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0315685/)? It is an Australian TV Show from 2002.

> Four ordinary kids face the extraordinary fact that a superhero really did exist in their city. The Silver Shadow is a forgotten crusader who waged a solitary war against crime and wrongdoing in the city 50 years ago. The kids discover a recording of the Silver Shadow's mind - an artificial intelligence the hero constructed in case he ever lost his fight against evil. The recording has a single purpose: to recruit a replacement. For our four kids, it's an opportunity of a lifetime - to learn and implement the Silver Shadow's heroic powers. They embark upon a bizarre double life - school kids by day, fledgling superheroes by night.

According to some information I found in this [other site](http://actf.com.au/worldwide-program-sales-catalog/show/legacy-of-the-silver-shadow), the Villain's name is: The Crab.

> Josh, Alex, Campbell and Gretel are thrown together when they discover the underground headquarters of the Silver Shadow, a long-forgotten dead superhero.  Although defeated in the 1950s by **his arch enemy, the Crab**, the Silver Shadow lives on as a digital recording in an old computer.
>
> Reactivated, he convinces the unlikely team to take up his battle against evil and injustice. Meanwhile, in a retirement home across town, the elderly Crab has begun training his grand-daughter Fiona to take over the family business…

(My emphasis)

[image: Silver Shadow Team]

**BONUS**

I found this [PDF](http://actf.com.au/assets/the_learning_centre/actf_lotss__6_ws_who_is_the_ss.pdf) from the same site as the previous link, that seems like a kid's exercise about the Silver Shadow. It has some additional information that adds up to your description:

> Across town, **The Crab, now in …….. seventies and wheelchair-bound**, begins to
> train his grand-daughter Fiona to take ……………. his evil empire and bring his
> plans for world domination to ……………….. The Shadow sighs.

(Again my emphasis)

Comment: I can't believe somebody found it! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! 
It brings back so many memories!

Comment: @user22360 Hey! No problem, man! Glad that it was it! :)